# Where is pcd_viewer on ROS fuerte?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In electric, I can run:

```
  rosrun pcl pcd_viewer office_chair_scene_360.pcd
```

But I can run it on ROS fuerte.

```
  sam@sam:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/bin$ rosrun pcl pcd_viewer office_chair_scene_360.pcd
  [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named pcd_viewer below /opt/ros/fuerte/share/pcl
  sam@sam:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/bin$
```

Is something I'm missing?

Where is it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41456/where-is-pcd_viewer-on-ros-fuerte?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ which pcd_viewer

/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/pcd_viewer

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-16**:
Why I can't click this is the right answer? It doesn't work when I click it. Thank you~